# Panda3D documentation, manual, and tutorials for offline viewing?

Tags: python, manuals

Is there a way to get the Panda3D's manual and tutorials available for offline viewing? I'm going on a business trip and I will spend a good deal of time at the airports and on long flights. I'd love to get started on Panda3D while in flight. Is there a way to get all that information available for offline, or use some program to download the tutorials and manual webpages?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you go to the Downloads section, under Snapshot Builds, you can find the documentation bundled as a zipfile or as chm, ready for downloading:

- [Snapshot Builds page](http://www.panda3d.org/buildbot/)
- [Python Doc](http://www.panda3d.org/buildbot/builds/manual-2010.11.29-64-python.zip)
- [Cxx Doc](http://www.panda3d.org/buildbot/builds/manual-2010.11.29-64-cxx.zip)

Answer (score 0):

The manual for version 1.5.0 is available [here](http://www.panda3d.org/download/panda3d-1.5.0/manual-1.5.0.zip).